# Bit operation question

Tags: bit

Is there a way to find the bit that has been set the least amount of times from using only bit operations?

For example, if I have three bit arrays:

```
11011001

11100000  
11101101
```

the bits in position 3 and 5 are set to 1 in only 1 of the three vectors.

I currently have an `o(n)` solution where n is the number of bits in the bitarray, where I go through each bit in the bitarray and increment each time there is a 1, but for some reason I think there is a `o(1)` solution that I can use with few bitwise operations. Can anyone advise? Thanks.

Comment: Are you always going to have 3 bit arrays, or can you have a lot more?

Comment: it would be rare to have cases of more than 10 arrays

Comment: or-ing the numbers will yield a zero for the bits that are set 0 times, like bit 1 in your example. I can't think of anything offhand for bits set once or more than once.

Comment: There may be a trick one can play based on the fact that you don't want to know the count, just which bit appears the least.  But nothing specific is coming to me just now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a duplicate/shift/mask approach to separate the bits and maybe be a little faster than an iterative bit shift scheme, if the total number of values is limited.

Eg for each "bits" 8-bit value, assuming no more than 15 values:

```
bits1 = (bits >> 3) & 0x11;
bits2 = (bits >> 2) & 0x11;
bits3 = (bits >> 1) & 0x11;
bits4 = bits & 0x11;
bitsSum1 += bits1;
bitsSum2 += bits2;
bitsSum3 += bits3;
bitsSum4 += bits4;
```

Then, at the end, break each bitsSumN value into two 4-bit counts.

Comment: I'll add that you can easily extend the above to 16-bit, 32-bit, or 64-bit (or even wider, if your language has them) values, by simply using larger hex constants.  And for more than 15 values you could do the operations in groups of 15, breaking the bitsSumN values apart into individual values after every 15 and summing those separately.  Also, if the number of values is large and their width is less than a register, you can do several values simultaneously in one register, then combine the appropriate sums at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to reflect the bit array.  In your example:

```
111
111
011
100
101
001
000
101
```

And then use the [standard bit counting methods](http://gurmeet.net/puzzles/fast-bit-counting-routines/) to count the number of bits set.

Doing this naively would most likely be slower than the normal approach, but you could try to adjust the algorithms to pull the bits from different words instead of the techniques they use.  The fastest techniques look at multiple bits at a time, though, so would seemingly be difficult to optimize in your case.

Answer (score 1):

if you're going to have 16 or less arrays, treat the bit patterns as hexadecimal numbers (instead of binary) and just add them together. but I'm afraid that it will still be less efficient than your o(n) solution. (and yes I realize that adding isn't a bitwise operation.)

Comment: In the askers example, you'd add D9 to E0 to get 1B9. How would that help?

Comment: no, I'd add 0x11011001 to 0x11100000 to 0x11101101 and get 0x33212102

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to have 15 items or fewer, I'd suggest that you start by distilling every group of three numbers into two, and then each group of fifteen into four.  Something like:

```
  uint32 x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1, ... x4,y4,z4; // Input values
  uint32 even0,even1,...even4,odd0...odd4;
  uint lowereven,lowerodd,uppereven,upperodd;

  even0 = (x0 & 0x55555555) + (y0 & 0x55555555) + (z0 & 0x555555555);
  odd0 = ((x0>>1) & 0x55555555) + ((y0>>1) & 0x55555555) + ((z0>>1) & 0x555555555);
  ... then do likewise for even1...even4 and odd1...odd4

  lowereven = ((even0 & 0x333333333) + (even1 & 0x33333333) + (even2 & 0x33333333)...;
  lowerodd = ((even0 & 0x333333333) + (even1 & 0x33333333) + (even2 & 0x33333333)...;
  uppereven = ((even0 >> 2) & 0x33333333) + ((even1 >> 2) & 0x33333333) + ...;
  oddeven = ((odd0 >> 2) & 0x33333333) + ((odd1 >> 2) & 0x33333333) + ...;
```

After those operations, the four values will hold bit counts for all the bits.  LowerEven will hold the counts for bits 0, 4, 8, 16, etc.; LowerOdd holds 1, 5, 9, etc.; UpperEven holds 2, 6, 10, etc.; UpperOdd holds 3, 7, 11, etc.

If one had more than 15 numbers, one could handle up to 255 numbers in groups of 15 by doing the above for each group, and then using eight statements to combine all the groups.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that if each bit would have some amount of leading zeros prepended then adding all the input values would yield the bitcount of each, we would just have to mask it out or something of the sort to retrieve it. Then the bit counting itself becomes trivial, but it raises other questions such as:

- How do I transform my input into the format on which I would like to operate?
- How do I retrieve my bit counts once the operation is performed?
- Should I be storing my input in the transformed format in the first place?
- What is the maximum bit count?

In the below code I decided to support a maximum bit count of 15, but it could easily be extended to 255. I decided to only consider well-formed input to the function (no empty or too-large input arrays). And that even though the assembly generated to access the bit fields by the caller will likely involve some shifts or masks, that that is okay.

This implementation uses a look-up table for the expansion, and though I didn't profile it, I think it should be quite a bit faster than the looping bit-by-bit solution.

```
struct BitCount
{
    unsigned char bit0 : 4;
    unsigned char bit1 : 4;
    unsigned char bit2 : 4;
    unsigned char bit3 : 4;
    unsigned char bit4 : 4;
    unsigned char bit5 : 4;
    unsigned char bit6 : 4;
    unsigned char bit7 : 4;
    unsigned char bit8 : 4;
    unsigned char bit9 : 4;
    unsigned char bitA : 4;
    unsigned char bitB : 4;
    unsigned char bitC : 4;
    unsigned char bitD : 4;
    unsigned char bitE : 4;
    unsigned char bitF : 4;
};

void CountBits(const short *invals, unsigned incount, BitCount &bitcount)
{
    assert(incount && incount <= 0xF && sizeof bitcount == 8);
    static const unsigned expand[256] = {
        //      _0          _1          _2          _3          _4          _5          _6          _7          _8          _9          _A          _B          _C          _D          _E          _F
        0x00000000, 0x00000001, 0x00000010, 0x00000011, 0x00000100, 0x00000101, 0x00000110, 0x00000111, 0x00001000, 0x00001001, 0x00001010, 0x00001011, 0x00001100, 0x00001101, 0x00001110, 0x00001111,   // 0_
        0x00010000, 0x00010001, 0x00010010, 0x00010011, 0x00010100, 0x00010101, 0x00010110, 0x00010111, 0x00011000, 0x00011001, 0x00011010, 0x00011011, 0x00011100, 0x00011101, 0x00011110, 0x00011111,   // 1_
        0x00100000, 0x00100001, 0x00100010, 0x00100011, 0x00100100, 0x00100101, 0x00100110, 0x00100111, 0x00101000, 0x00101001, 0x00101010, 0x00101011, 0x00101100, 0x00101101, 0x00101110, 0x00101111,   // 2_
        0x00110000, 0x00110001, 0x00110010, 0x00110011, 0x00110100, 0x00110101, 0x00110110, 0x00110111, 0x00111000, 0x00111001, 0x00111010, 0x00111011, 0x00111100, 0x00111101, 0x00111110, 0x00111111,   // 3_
        0x01000000, 0x01000001, 0x01000010, 0x01000011, 0x01000100, 0x01000101, 0x01000110, 0x01000111, 0x01001000, 0x01001001, 0x01001010, 0x01001011, 0x01001100, 0x01001101, 0x01001110, 0x01001111,   // 4_
        0x01010000, 0x01010001, 0x01010010, 0x01010011, 0x01010100, 0x01010101, 0x01010110, 0x01010111, 0x01011000, 0x01011001, 0x01011010, 0x01011011, 0x01011100, 0x01011101, 0x01011110, 0x01011111,   // 5_
        0x01100000, 0x01100001, 0x01100010, 0x01100011, 0x01100100, 0x01100101, 0x01100110, 0x01100111, 0x01101000, 0x01101001, 0x01101010, 0x01101011, 0x01101100, 0x01101101, 0x01101110, 0x01101111,   // 6_
        0x01110000, 0x01110001, 0x01110010, 0x01110011, 0x01110100, 0x01110101, 0x01110110, 0x01110111, 0x01111000, 0x01111001, 0x01111010, 0x01111011, 0x01111100, 0x01111101, 0x01111110, 0x01111111,   // 7_
        0x10000000, 0x10000001, 0x10000010, 0x10000011, 0x10000100, 0x10000101, 0x10000110, 0x10000111, 0x10001000, 0x10001001, 0x10001010, 0x10001011, 0x10001100, 0x10001101, 0x10001110, 0x10001111,   // 8_
        0x10010000, 0x10010001, 0x10010010, 0x10010011, 0x10010100, 0x10010101, 0x10010110, 0x10010111, 0x10011000, 0x10011001, 0x10011010, 0x10011011, 0x10011100, 0x10011101, 0x10011110, 0x10011111,   // 9_
        0x10100000, 0x10100001, 0x10100010, 0x10100011, 0x10100100, 0x10100101, 0x10100110, 0x10100111, 0x10101000, 0x10101001, 0x10101010, 0x10101011, 0x10101100, 0x10101101, 0x10101110, 0x10101111,   // A_
        0x10110000, 0x10110001, 0x10110010, 0x10110011, 0x10110100, 0x10110101, 0x10110110, 0x10110111, 0x10111000, 0x10111001, 0x10111010, 0x10111011, 0x10111100, 0x10111101, 0x10111110, 0x10111111,   // B_
        0x11000000, 0x11000001, 0x11000010, 0x11000011, 0x11000100, 0x11000101, 0x11000110, 0x11000111, 0x11001000, 0x11001001, 0x11001010, 0x11001011, 0x11001100, 0x11001101, 0x11001110, 0x11001111,   // C_
        0x11010000, 0x11010001, 0x11010010, 0x11010011, 0x11010100, 0x11010101, 0x11010110, 0x11010111, 0x11011000, 0x11011001, 0x11011010, 0x11011011, 0x11011100, 0x11011101, 0x11011110, 0x11011111,   // D_
        0x11100000, 0x11100001, 0x11100010, 0x11100011, 0x11100100, 0x11100101, 0x11100110, 0x11100111, 0x11101000, 0x11101001, 0x11101010, 0x11101011, 0x11101100, 0x11101101, 0x11101110, 0x11101111,   // E_
        0x11110000, 0x11110001, 0x11110010, 0x11110011, 0x11110100, 0x11110101, 0x11110110, 0x11110111, 0x11111000, 0x11111001, 0x11111010, 0x11111011, 0x11111100, 0x11111101, 0x11111110, 0x11111111 }; // F_
    unsigned *const   countLo = (unsigned*)&bitcount;
    unsigned *const   countHi = (unsigned*)&bitcount + 1;
    *countLo = expand[*invals & 0xFF];
    *countHi = expand[*invals++ >> 8];
    switch (incount)
    {
        case 0xF:
            *countLo += expand[*invals & 0xFF];
            *countHi += expand[*invals++ >> 8];
        case 0xE:
            *countLo += expand[*invals & 0xFF];
            *countHi += expand[*invals++ >> 8];
        case 0xD:
            *countLo += expand[*invals & 0xFF];
            *countHi += expand[*invals++ >> 8];
        case 0xC:
            *countLo += expand[*invals & 0xFF];
            *countHi += expand[*invals++ >> 8];
        case 0xB:
            *countLo += expand[*invals & 0xFF];
            *countHi += expand[*invals++ >> 8];
        case 0xA:
            *countLo += expand[*invals & 0xFF];
            *countHi += expand[*invals++ >> 8];
        case 0x9:
            *countLo += expand[*invals & 0xFF];
            *countHi += expand[*invals++ >> 8];
        case 0x8:
            *countLo += expand[*invals & 0xFF];
            *countHi += expand[*invals++ >> 8];
        case 0x7:
            *countLo += expand[*invals & 0xFF];
            *countHi += expand[*invals++ >> 8];
        case 0x6:
            *countLo += expand[*invals & 0xFF];
            *countHi += expand[*invals++ >> 8];
        case 0x5:
            *countLo += expand[*invals & 0xFF];
            *countHi += expand[*invals++ >> 8];
        case 0x4:
            *countLo += expand[*invals & 0xFF];
            *countHi += expand[*invals++ >> 8];
        case 0x3:
            *countLo += expand[*invals & 0xFF];
            *countHi += expand[*invals++ >> 8];
        case 0x2:
            *countLo += expand[*invals & 0xFF];
            *countHi += expand[*invals >> 8];
    };
}
```

---

**EDIT** You can skip the above table look-up on a 64-bit system if you widen the bit count values from 4 bits to 8 bits by taking advantage of the properties of multiplication.

This is the property we are interested in (a, b, c, and d are 0 or 1, and n is a binary number):
n * (a * 2^3 + b * 2^2 + c *2^1 + d * 2^0) <=> ((a * n) << 3) + ((b * n) << 2) + ((c * n) << 1) + ((d * n) << 0)

So if we cast a byte to a 64-bit int and carefully pick a multiplier we can end up with a 0 or a 1 in the first bit of every byte of the product. Here is such a multiplier:

00000000 00000010 00000100 00001000 00010000 00100000 01000000 10000001
or 0x002040810204081

So, we can expand a byte to 64 bits like this:

```
unsigned char b = ...

// this operation can be used in substitution of the below look-up table
// (if the code is written for 8-bit wide count, instead of 4-bit wide counts)
unsigned __int64 valx = ((unsigned __int64)b * 0x002040810204081) & 0x0101010101010101;
```

We can then extract bit counts like this on little endian systems

```
union ResultType {
  unsigned __int64 result;
  unsigned char    bitcount[8]; // bitcount[x] is the number of times the x-th most significant bit appeared
};

ResultType r;
r.result = val1 + val2 + val3 + ...; // up to 255 values can be summed before we risk overflow

r.bitcount[2] // how many times the 00000100 bit was set
```